# Subdomain point to Amazon S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, namecheap

I am a little bit confused with subdomain point to S3 bucket.

I have domain called mydomain.com from NameCheap.com and my hosting server is Hostgater.

So my website is up and running.

I have a lot of mp3 files. So I have created Amazon S3 bucket call 
media.mydomain.com

So I got my static s3 website URL as follow.
http://media.mydomain.com.s3-website-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/

I want to point this url to my subdomain, media.mydomain.com.

May I know how and where to point? NameCheap or Hostgator.

I have created subdomain in hostgator but it can only redirect to S3 URL

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make a new DNS record in Namecheap for this task

In your Namecheap account, go to **Manage** your domain, then **Advanced DNS**, and **Add new Record** with **CName** type

- Host: Enter your subdomain `media`
- Value: Enter `media.mydomain.com.s3-website-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com.` (with a dot . at the end)
- TTL: Automatic

Save all changes and wait for about 1 hour for the new record to take effect.

Comment: Hi Rocherlee, thanks for your reply. My name server is HostGator. So I have created CName type in HostGator. It is working now.